# C# I want to change the bytes allocated

Tags: c#, filestream

```
            Byte[] mtime = new Byte[4];
            mtime = BitConverter.GetBytes(root.LastWriteTime.ToBinary());
            fs.Write(mtime, 0, mtime.Length);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqmBd.png)

When Save That Binary File. It(LastWriteTime) occupies 8Bytes.
I want 'LastWriteTime' only use 4Bytes.
What should I do?
Is there a way?

sorry, I'm Bad English....

Comment: Well, it's a timestamp - it likely represents the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970. It needs 8 bytes for that much precision. There are ways you could *perhaps* represent only the date, but it would take specialized conversion. Maybe you could explain why you want to save 4 bytes?

Comment: Sorry. In the image above, That's a not 16 Bytes. It's 8Bytes Block. I made a mistake.

Comment: OK. I understand What you say. Can I ask you another question? That timestamp can only save 8bytes?(default value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot shrink the representation of a DateTime object without losing information (i.e. precision). If you are okay with losing information, you merely need to decide which information is most important to you. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2695525/5812435) shows, you can truncate information from the underlying data type (a long), and just take the information you need.

> If you need millisecond precision only, why not lose the least significant bits
>
> ```
> int timeStamp = (int)(DateTime.Now.Ticks >> 10) // lose smallest 10 bits
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your help!